# Change indent of section* in cls file

Tags: sectioning, indentation, document-classes

I am using a custom latex class (https://github.com/quantum-journal/quantum-journal/blob/master/quantumarticle.cls). Using this class, the titles of unnumbered sections are indented slightly. However, I would like them flush left (like in the standard article class).

How does one, in general, change the indentation of unnumbered sections in the class file?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This seems to be an undocumented artefact of revtex's `ltxutil`  package which is included via `ltxgrid` package, loading that into `article` shows the same effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\do@output@cclv \relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{ltxutil}

\begin{document}

\section{ZZZZ}
zzz

\tracingall
\section*{ZZZZ}
zzz
\tracingnone

\end{document}
```

I would follow the usual advice with publisher styles, just assume whatever output you get is the output that they need. the whole reason for a publisher style is to remove design choices from the author and they are not (and this one in particular isn't) designed  to be customised.

---

[image]

That said if you want to fix the package in this case you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\do@output@cclv \relax
\makeatother
\usepackage{ltxutil}


\makeatletter
\def\@hang@froms#1#2{\noindent#1#2}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{ZZZZ}
zzz


\section*{ZZZZ}
zzz


\end{document}
```

Somewhat amusingly I find that the part with the change that breaks the `\section*` layout was commented as

```
% \begin{macro}{\@ssect}
% Put brace characters back where they were before David Carlisle got at them
% (as if \cmd\@hangfrom\ has two arguments).
```

followed by a breaking change, the small addition in the code above at least restores `\noindent` so the section heading is flush left as intended.